# Printing multiple UIElements in Silverlight 4

Tags: xaml, printing, silverlight-4.0, uielement

I have a page that has two `UIElement`s that need to be printed, one is a `StackPanel` and the other is a custom graph control for displaying test scores. The graph control could be any length based on the number of tests to display, so sometimes I will be able to fit both on one page and other times will need separate pages.

Printing them on separate pages works fine as I just set the UIElement to the pagevisual, the problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to combine them for printing on a single page. I tried creating a StackPanel in the codebehind and adding the elements to it, but since an element can only have one parent I have to create temporary objects to hold each one while I remove from the original parent and then give the temp to the new StackPanel. The problem is that after I do that all the bound data goes missing

Any ideas would be awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding actual elements to the `StackPanel` for printing, you can create snapshots of those elements and add only images to the `StackPanel`. You can use the following method to created an `Image` from a `UIElement`:

```
public static Image CreateElementImage(UIElement element) 
{
    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)element.RenderSize.Width, (int)element.RenderSize.Height);

    Array.Clear(bitmap.Pixels, 0, bitmap.Pixels.Length);
    bitmap.Render(element, element.RenderTransform);
    bitmap.Invalidate();

    var result = new Image {Source = bitmap};

    return result;
}
```

Comment: In WPF, an easier way to accomplish this would be with a VisualBrush.  Not available for SL though

Comment: Okay, so my next question would be is there any way to take a picture of only a certain part of the UIElement? Say I want to use the entire page as the element, calculate how many pages I will need, and then take a picture of it from the top to -1024, then -1024 to -2048, and so on until I have a picture of every page.Is this possible?

Comment: @Josh - You can try to play around with that WriteableBitmap. It could be that you can render a specific part of the UIElement to it. Unfortunately, I don't have a complete solution for you.

Comment: Or maybe is there  a way to split the bitmap into pieces after it's created? I could take an image of the entire page, then somehow divide it up into images that will fit on a printed page.

Answer (score 0):

Or just put the image in a `Canvas` and then compare `Canvas`'s height and image height to calculate number of pages.